# Create a while loop that break after a certain tries - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

## Description

I'm trying to write a while loop to my monitor API.
The goal is to call the API until the percent is reaching 100.
I want to call it every 5 seconds. Usually in 30 seconds, the percent will reach 100%.
I want to throw the error after 10 tries which is equal to 50 seconds.

---

## I've tried

```
let monitor = await Service.monitor(session,taskId);
let percent = JSON.parse(monitor).result[0].data.percent;

let tryCount = 0;
let tryMax = 10;
while (percent < 100 || tryCount < tryMax) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        let percent = JSON.parse(monitor).result[0].data.percent;
        tryCount++;
    }, 5000);

    console.log('in a while loop ',tryCount, percent);

    if(tryCount == 10){
        var err = new Error('Error')
        throw err
    }
}
```

---

## Result

I got so many

```
in a while loop  0 0
in a while loop  0 0
...
in a while loop  0 0
in a while loop  0 0
```

---

## Question

Why my `tryCount` keep showing as 0 and not increment?

How would one create a `while-loop` that does something like that ?

Comment: Your solution is to just use a setInterval loop, I'm typing up the answer now.

Comment: You're calling thousands of `setTimeout()`s, but you need to do nothing for 5 seconds instead. Either use `setInterval()` or put the check in a function and call it in the `setTimeout` callback.

Comment: `> Why my tryCount keep showing as 0 and not increment?`

Because `while (percent < 100 || tryCount < tryMax)` blocks the event loop.

Answer (score 3):

You need to refresh the monitor variable, instead of just re-parsing. You had the right idea, just had to take it further

Also, I moved you to a setInterval from a while loop, that way you can run things on an automatically timed loop, the "correct" way to do it

```
let monitor = await Service.monitor(session,taskId);
let percent = JSON.parse(monitor).result[0].data.percent;

let tryCount = 0;
let tryMax = 10;
setInterval(function(){(percent < 100 || tryCount < tryMax) {
    if(percent < 100 || tryCount < tryMax){
    monitor = await Service.monitor(session,taskId);
    let percent = JSON.parse(monitor).result[0].data.percent;
    tryCount++;
    console.log('in a while loop ',tryCount, percent);

    if(tryCount == 10){
        var err = new Error('Error')
        throw err
    }
    }else{
    clearInterval(this);
    }
},5000)
```

And I'm assuming you're somehow reloading `monitor`, because even if you re-parse it, if it's a connection on a different server, you'll need to reload that.

Comment: What is `(percent < 100 || tryCount < tryMax){` at the begining of the callback function is supposed to do?

Comment: I think it is a typo, he had.

Comment: Also, `tryCount` is still not incrementing.